# Update database with Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have this Parse cloud job

```
Parse.Cloud.job("AuthorSearchField", function(request, response) {

    //get all author
    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query("Author");
    //for each item
    testItemsQuery.each(function (testItem) {
      //set search field
      testItem.set("searchField",testItem.get("name").toLowerCase());
      testItem.save()
    }).then(function() {
      response.success("Set searchField");
    }, function(error) {
      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    });
});
```

This job is used to fill "searchField" with content of "name"

I execute this job and everything is fine :

[image]

But, nothing is updated in base database

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to this party but here we go:

In your code inside the each function you don't return a promise so the server just runs through the whole thing.
Try:

`return testItem.save();`

I'd also suggest not saving all those items one by one but creating batches and saving them let's say 100 at a time.